# How to join hexadecimal values in c

Tags: c

```
void *val1 = (uint8_t []){0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};

size_t val1_len = 20;

void* val2 = (uint8_t[]){0x1, 0xf, 0xc, 0x3};

size_t val2_len = 4;

void *val3 = (uint8_t[]){0x1, 0x1, 0xc, 0x4, 0x5, 0x7, 0xa, 0x4};

size_t val3_len = 8;
```

I have these values called `val1`, `val2`, `val3`. Now how can I concatenate them such such that I get

`val1` followed by `val2`  followed by `val3` as the output

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?  Are you trying to print them with addition signs between the values?  Are you trying to just store them in a single buffer together?

Comment: Create another array whose size is `20 + 4 + 8`, then loop through the original arrays copying the elements.

Comment: @Barmar Assuming that is what the OP is looking for as the end result, why wouldn't you just use `memcpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void *val4 = malloc(val1_len + val2_len + val3_len);
memcpy(val4, val1, val1_len);
memcpy(val4+val1_len, val2, val2_len);
memcpy(val4+val1_len+val2_len, val3, val3_len);
```

Comment: To be a bit picky, arithmetic on `void *` is a GNU C extension and perhaps not suitable for an answer. No idea why you don't use `uint8_t` pointers.

Comment: @unwind Yikes.  Yes.  I used `void *` in this answer only because the OP did in the question, and I overlooked the fact that the pointer arithmetic was therefore *muy problemático*.